# Get Ajax request implementation without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing a pixel library to do an AJAX request so I'm not allowed to use any helper.

```
function ajax(options) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var opts = Object.assign({
    withCredentials: false,
    method: 'GET'
  }, options);

  xhr.withCredentials = options.withCredentials;
  xhr.open(opts.method, opts.url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/plain');
  xhr.send(null);
  return {
    done: function(cb) {
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function onStateChange() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
            cb(this.responseText);
          } else {
            cb('error');
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.ontimeout = function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        cb(false);
      };

      xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        cb(false);
      };
    }
  }
};

ajax({
  url: '/echo/json'
}).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
})
```

I also have my code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ch7b4jo/2/) in case anyone wants to test the code.

**Note**: This library doesn't support POST as I want to keep the code as less as possible. It will only support GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ajax()` function gives me a good first impression. The structure seems sound and the event handling well done - the `done()` event handler is called exactly once (someone else might want to confirm, though).

A few suggestions:

- `var opts = Object.assign({...}, options);`

  `opts` vs. `options` is inconsistent and carries no semantics. Reassigning to `options` would mutate the argument which could cause issues for the user. jQuery names the merged options and defaults `settings`, which *might* be a little bit more clear.
- `if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {`

  This line seems good for now. You might want to check 304 in a future version when allowing users to supply caching headers. However, such requests don't respond with data and are probably not within the intended use of your library right now.
- `xhr.send(null);`

  The `send` method accepts an optional parameter which is ignored and set to `null` for GET requests. Therefore, I would recommend the simpler `xhr.send()`.
- `if (this.readyState === 4) {`

  Add more semantic by replacing `4` with `XMLHttpRequest.DONE` - [not available in old browsers such as IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898559/problem-with-xmlhttprequest-done-values).
- `cb('error');`

  This seems like a design flaw to me. A user cannot distinguish between an `'error'` string received from the server vs. supplied as a result of an invalid HTTP status code. You already supply `false` on multiple occasions - when a network level error or timeout occurs - which is easily distinguished from a valid response by type checking. Why not supply `false` in the above case, too? If that's not an option, supply an error status flag or object or introduce `error` callback(s).

Answer (score -1):

I updated your code a little bit. Have a nice day ;)

[**UPDATE**]:

I have used `arrow functions` to write cleaner and shorter code.
You can see it for example at the end of the `ajax` function (`ontimeout` and `onerror`)

**before:**

```
  xhr.ontimeout = function(e) {
    console.error(e);
    cb(false);
  };
```

**after:**

```
  xhr.ontimeout = e => reject(e);
```

Also i've used the `spread operator` to extend the `opts` variable.
*Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator*

`ajax`, `xhr` and `opts` changed from `var` to `const`, because theire values never change.

The `ajax` function now returns a `Promise` instead of calling a function.
Better error handling, chaining and state of the art.

I've removed all `console.log` calls and always return an `Error` Object for better handling instead of `false`.

---

```js
const ajax = (options) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // request options
  const opts = {
    withCredentials: false,
    method: options.method || 'GET',
    ...options
  };

  xhr.withCredentials = options.withCredentials;
  xhr.open(opts.method, opts.url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', opts.type || 'text/plain');
  xhr.send(opts.body || null);

  // create promise to handle asynchron call
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
          // return errors if status is wrong (catch)
          reject(new Error(xhr.status));
        }
      }
    }

    // return errors on timeout (catch)
    xhr.ontimeout = e => reject(e);
    xhr.onerror = e => reject(e);
  })
}


ajax({
  url: '/echo/json',
  method: 'POST', // Standard: GET
  type: 'application/json', // Standard: text/plain
  body: {  // Standard: null
    form: 'data'
  }
}).then(data => data)
  // chaining. Handle returned `data` in next `then`
  .then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Very nice! Don't mind me suggesting a few additional ideas: The default options + options merging could be a bit more localized instead of all over the place. `opts.body || null` might set an incorrect `null` POST body for e.g. `opts.body = 0`. Also, the callback receives an `Error` when an application layer error occurs (HTTP status code) but a `ProgressEvent` when a transport layer error occurs (xhr.onerror) which seems a bit quirky.

Comment: Just rewriting code without explaining what you rewrote and why does not really give much value to either the original question poster or to others reading the answer.  Therefore it doesn't really amount to a code review at all.  Can you elaborate here?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right. I am new to this and learning with every post. I've updated my answer.